# Outlook add-in to retrieve "auto replies" settings from Office 365, using VSTO?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to create an Outlook add-in to retrieve my "auto-replies" settings from Office 365 so that I can update a specific database with 'start date' and 'end date' ( that we use to set the auto-replies in Outlook).

I found solutions related to Outlook exchange server but we are not using an exchange server and everything is being managed by Office 365.

What Microsoft.office.interop.outlook property holds the "auto-reply" settings?

Answer (score 0):

OOF on/off can be retrieved from the store object, but the date range can only be accessed using EWS (Exchange Web Services).
And Office 365 **is** Exchange (version 2019).